# Can't figure out why simple method is infinitely looping in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

It's just a simple little method that gets user input to convert an integer from decimal to binary. It uses do-while loops to restart and verify valid input. When it catches an InputMismatchException, it starts to infinitely loop this:

```
Must enter a positive integer, try again.
Enter positive integer for binary conversion:
```

I don't know why the Scanner isn't causing the program to wait for new input when I call nextInt().

Here's the code for the method:

```
public static void main (String[] theArgs) {
    final Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean invalidInput = false;
    boolean running = true;
    int input = 0;
    do {
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter positive integer for binary conversion:");
            try {
                input = inputScanner.nextInt();
                if (input < 1) {
                    System.out.println("Must be a positive integer, try again.");
                    invalidInput = true;
                } else {
                    invalidInput = false;
                }
            } catch (final InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Must enter a positive integer, try again.");
                invalidInput = true;
            }
        } while (invalidInput);
        System.out.println(StackUtilities.decimalToBinary(input));
        System.out.println("Again? Enter 'n' for no, or anything else for yes:");
        if (inputScanner.next().equals("n")) {
            running = false;
        }
    } while (running);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing printing `input` ? Do you know which version of ""Must be a positive integer, try again." is printed (are you sure it is the one in the exception?). Lookup "how to debug small programs" for more hints.

Comment: If you enter an invalid value, `nextInt()` throws `InputMismatchException` **without consuming the invalid value**, so when you loop back, it's still there. Add e.g. `next()` inside the `catch` block to consume the invalid value.

Answer (score 4):

You need to clear the buffer when user enters the wrong type of input, Just use `inputScanner.next()` or `inputScanner.nextLine()` in `catch` block to clear the buffer

```
catch (final InputMismatchException e) {
      inputScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Must enter a positive integer, try again.");
            invalidInput = true;
        }
```